# "SQLITE_ERROR: cannot start a transaction within a transaction" with BEGIN ... COMMIT transaction control

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I had been getting the above-mentioned "SQLITE_ERROR: cannot start a transaction within a transaction" error during my database initialization process, but did find that there were some suggestions for best practises: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899828/best-practices-for-using-sqlite3-node-js) and [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/3).

So, I adjusted my code to add the db.run("BEGIN") and db.run("COMMIT") bookends to hopefully fix the issue, but the error still persists.

Here is what my code looks like:

I call the various initialization functions:

```
intializeMyTable1(...);
intializeMyTable2(...);
...
intializeMyTableN(...);
```

Each intialize function is roughly the same:

```
initializeMyTable1: function(...){ 
...          
db.run("BEGIN")           
db.run("CREATE TABLE if not exists MyTable1 (...)", function (err) {
  if (err !== null) {
    logger.error("Database Error:" + err);
  }
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < SomeNumber; i++) {
      db.run("INSERT INTO MyTable1 (...) VALUES (...)", function (err) {
        if (err !== null) {
          ...
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
db.run("COMMIT");
...
}
```

I've tried db.run("END") instead of db.run("COMMIT") - same error.

What I did find is that if I run only one of the initialization functions at a time, I don't get the error, but if I chain the initialization functions, running them one after the other, I get the error.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated!

EDITS: Minor typo fixes

Comment: I dont know NodeJS. But Your function is executing `db.run("BEGIN") ` in each caling. Put `db.run("BEGIN")` as run one time only. Also `db.run("COMMIT")` at end of loop.

Comment: try `db.run("BEGIN  TRANSACTION")` also.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried db.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION"). Also, each function only called "BEGIN" and "COMMIT" once - they are book-ends. But perhaps due to the asynchronous nature of Node/JS, maybe they are overlapping. Let me take a look into this.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you omitted a call to `db.serialize()` in your posts you did not actually fix your error.

All the statements are executed asynchronously, which means that `db.run` does not actually *run* the statement but rather enqueues it. Enqueued statements are executed in parallel if not explicitly wrapped in `db.serialize()`.

Thus, the following is not expected to be executed in the given order, one after the other:

```
db.run("BEGIN");
db.run("*do sql stuff*");
db.run("COMMIT");
db.run("BEGIN");
db.run("*do sql stuff*");
db.run("COMMIT");
```

It might be executed as

```
db.run("BEGIN");
db.run("BEGIN");
db.run("COMMIT");
db.run("COMMIT");
db.run("*do sql stuff*");
db.run("*do sql stuff*");
```

or any other random order. That explains your error message "cannot start a transaction within a transaction".

Have a look at https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow.

Answer (score 1):

OK, made some minor changes to the code and it works now!

```
initializeMyTable1: function(...){ 
...    
// treat the CREATE as independent of my BEGIN ... COMMIT flow  
db.exec("CREATE TABLE if not exists MyTable1 (...)", function (err) {
  if (err !== null) {
    logger.error("Database Error:" + err);
  }
  else {
    // BEGIN ... COMMIT bookends only relate to INSERTs
    db.run("BEGIN");
    for (var i = 0; i < SomeNumber; i++) {
      db.run("INSERT INTO MyTable1 (...) VALUES (...)", function (err) {
        if (err !== null) {
          ...
        }
      });
    }
    db.run("COMMIT");
  }
});
...
}
```

Hope that helps anyone with similar problems.