# How does `db.serialize` work in `node-sqlite3`

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Recently I'm learning to use node and [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) to manipulate sqlite3, here is a sample.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE test(info TEXT)");
    db.run("INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('info1')");
})
db.close();
```

The documentation said that `db.serialized` was used to ensure SQL lines were executed in order, but I was confused, why wouldn't they get executed in order without `db.serialize`, after all they would be pulled from the event queue and executed in order? How does it work here?

And if there is only one sql to be executed, is it safe to run it without `db.serialize` as follows?

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
db.run("CREATE TABLE test(info TEXT)");
db.close();
```

Comment: Probably one of the reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899872/1936319

Answer (score 53):

Each command inside the `serialize()` function is guaranteed to **finish** executing before the next one starts.

In your example, the `CREATE TABLE` will finish before the `INSERT` gets run.  If you didn't use `serialize()` then the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements would be run in parallel.  They would start so quickly one after the other that the `INSERT` may actually finish before the table has been created, giving you an error about trying to insert data into a table that doesn't exist.

This is called a *race condition*, because every time you run your program you might get a different winner.  If `CREATE TABLE` wins the race then the program will work fine.  But if `INSERT` wins the race, the program will break with an error.  Since you can't control who wins the race, `serialize()` will stop `INSERT` from even starting until `CREATE TABLE` has reached the end, ensuring you get the same outcome every time.

In your second example with only one statement then `serialize()` is still required.  This is because `run()` starts the SQL query but **returns immediately**, leaving the query to run in the background.  Since your very next command is one to `close()` the database, you'll cut it off while the query is still running.

Since `serialize()` doesn't return until the last of its internal queries has completed, using it will hold off the `close()` until the query has completed.

If you were using a different type of query (say in response to a user clicking a button on a web page, where the database is left open between calls) then you probably wouldn't need `serialize()`.  It just depends whether the code that follows each query requires that the queries before it have completed or not.

When deciding whether to use `serialize()` or not, it can be helpful to think of any non-serialized queries as if they are commented out, and then see if the code would still work.  In your first example above, removing the `CREATE TABLE` command would break the following `INSERT` statement (because then there'd be no table to insert into), therefore these need to be serialised.  But if you had two `CREATE TABLE` commands then removing one would not affect the other, so those two commands would not have to be serialized.

*(This tip doesn't apply to `close()` however - the rule of thumb there is to only call `close()` once everything has finished running.)*

Comment: Is there some way to guarantee that the run() call will finish before the callback is called?  I'm using serialize with a savepoint, but intermittently the callback is returning but none of my serialized queries have run yet and I see my code calling close on the database before they run. this is a big problem since i'm trying to use data returned from these calls.

Comment: @Michael: Not sure what you mean by `run()` having a callback, but it sounds like this should be a new question rather than a comment so you can provide more detail.

Answer (score 7):

I found this in the [SQLite documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow):

> the Database#close method will always run in exclusive mode, meaning
>   it waits until all previous queries have completed and node-sqlite3
>   will not run any other queries while a close is pending.

So it looks like the answer to your final question is **yes**. If you only have one query to run, there's no need for the serialize function.  You don't need to worry about your database getting closed before the query finishes because SQLite is smart enough not to do that! :)