# Use sqlite3 in electron, db.serialize dose not work properly

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

package.json

```
{
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "^1.7.9",
    "electron-builder": "^19.37.2",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div id='database'></div>
  <script>
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('./test.db')
    db.serialize(function () {
      var stmt = db.all("select * from BK_GROUP", function (_, rows) {
        console.log('end1');
      })
      var stmt2 = db.all("select * from BK_GROUP", function (_, rows) {
        console.log('end2');
      })
    })
    console.log('out1');
    db.close();
  </script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I expect(according to sqlite3's api document https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow) this code should output like this

```
end1
end2
out1
```

but real output is

```
out1
end1
end2
```

I follow some instruction on web, install electron-rebuild, and run it

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

also it found sqlite3 and rebuild it, but this doesn't help.

I aslo add postinstall in package.json's scripts.

But if I run this code in pure node.js env, it outputs correct result.

---

More, if I run this code in electron, it outputs correctly(first print end, then out). The only difference is this code open database in memory, above open a file database locate on hard driver.

```
<body>
    <h1>electron-boilerplate-sqlite</h1>
    <ul id="database">
    </ul>
    <script>
      var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
      var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

      db.serialize(function() {
        db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
          stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
        }

        stmt.finalize();

        var rows = document.getElementById("database");
        db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
          var item = document.createElement("li");
          item.textContent = "" + row.id + ": " + row.info;
          rows.appendChild(item);
        });
        console.log('end')
        setTimeout(() => console.log('delay'), 1000);

      });
      console.log('out')

      db.close();
    </script>
  </body>
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

you misunderstood javascript, db serialize is callback function so the order of console.log is correct, but keep in mind one

[Since serialize() doesn't return until the last of its internal queries has completed, using it will hold off the close() until the query has completed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949724/how-does-db-serialize-work-in-node-sqlite3)